# Changing int variable has no effect

Tags: java, bluej

I am working on a NaturalSelectionSimulator and am experiencing an issue with changing the *X* int value of the creature.

```
for(Food f : food)
{
    if(f.x()-x==-1)
    {
        x--;
    }
    else if(f.x()-x==1)
    {
        x+=1;
        System.out.println("RIGHT MOVE F ");
    }
    else if(f.y()-y==-1)
    {
        y--;
    }
    else if(f.y()-y==1)
    {
        y++;
    }
}
```

f.x() returns the *X* int val of the food class, vice versa for f.y(). The print statement does run, yet the statement above it does not. Changing it back to x++; does not effect the outcome.

GitHub Link: https://github.com/JakeDavisCodes/NaturalSelectionSimulator

Comment: Where have you declared the variables `x` and `y`?

Comment: *"The print statement does run, yet the above statement does not"* --- That's impossible, so please **prove** that to us with a [**Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). --- *Hint:* Linking to 5 classes of code is not a **minimal** example.

Comment: Have you tried putting `System.out.println("x = " + x);` statements before and after `x += 1;` to observe what happens?

Comment: I think you might be changing the x field in your Creature class. Is that your intention?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somehwat ambiguous. Perhaps I misunderstood it, in which case this answer isn't relevant; in that case, please edit the question or wait for someone who does follow what you're asking here.

It *sounds* like you're confused about how variable passing works in java. When you have method `public int getX() { return this.x; }` that literally just returns the exact value. Upon invoking it, the  current value of the x field is retrieved and that is returned. It's, effectively, a copy. If you then take this value and assign it to your own variable (even if you call it 'x' too - that is immaterial, a pure coincidence that both bits of code chose the same name), you have a copy. If you then mess with it, you're just messing with your copy.

In java there is no way to change this behaviour. Either update the variable directly, for example by writing: `void setX(int newX) {this.x = newX; }` and doing: `f.setX(f.getX() + 1)`, or use a mutable container like `AtomicInteger`.